# How often do editors reach reviewers whose expertise don't match the paper?

Tags: peer-review, editors

It's inevitable that sometimes, editors will invite reviewers whose expertise don't match the paper very well ([example](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/71347/do-the-editors-of-journals-really-know-about-expertise-of-reviewers)).

How often does it actually happen, and what percentage is considered acceptable? I'm especially interested in answers from editors and/or publishers who have seen hundreds of reviewer invitations.

Tangentially related graphic from the reviewer's point of view:

[image]

Comment: Acceptable to whom? And the "distance" from the invited reviewer's expertise should probably be factored in.

Comment: @Anyon acceptable to the person supervising the editors - e.g., the editor-in-chief. "Distance" should be factored, but it's awfully hard to quantify, e.g. Stephen Hawking is obviously a physicist, but that doesn't mean he can review papers in condensed matter physics. So I don't see a way to do it other than to use the reviewer's self-reported "out of expertise" option.

Comment: I agree it will be tricky to quantify "distance", but it certainly factors in to how I answer invitations to review papers outside my expertise. If a paper is reasonably relevant, perhaps in the general field but using some specific formalism/technique I'm not equipped to review in a timely manner, I might explain what expertise I think is required and suggest other potential reviewers. On the other hand, an example like you mention would give me a bad impression of the journal and might not get a response.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I'd guess at least some journals/publishers will have statistics on this they don't make public, but here are a couple of data points:

[Raniga, S. B. (2020). Decline to review a manuscript: insight and implications for AJR reviewers, authors, and editorial staff. American Journal of Roentgenology, 214(4), 723-726.](https://www.ajronline.org/doi/full/10.2214/AJR.19.22000) considered three years' worth of decline-to-review responses to American Journal of Roentgenology, and found that 12.6% (n=1181) of the declined reviews were given the "not an area of expertise" response. At the same time, 49.4% of the decline responses were due to lack of time ("overcommitted"), and 34.7% were for unspecified reasons. In the text it is stated that a total of 26,290 reviewers were invited. If we assume all numbers given refer to invitations rather than unique individual reviewers, that means ~4.5% of the invitations were declined for being outside the reviewer's expertise.

[Willis, M. (2016). Why do peer reviewers decline to review manuscripts? A study of reviewer invitation responses. Learned Publishing, 29(1), 5-7.](https://doi.org/10.1002/leap.1006) looked at a medical journal published by Wiley over a 5-month period and found that 4.3% of all invitation responses were "Decline to review – not my field".

Comment: I'm surprised at how low those numbers are. It's perhaps worth think about both field and journal. I tend to decline 1 or 2 reviews every week for being outside my area, far more than I actually review. But they tend to be from what you might called lower quality higher volume journals.

Comment: It's surprising how both these papers find that "no time" is about 4-5x more likely than "out of expertise", but the most common reason given by reviewers (as in the OP) is "no time".

Comment: @Allure It seems quite likely that there is (significant) variation from journal to journal and between fields, like Ian suggested. A well-run and long-established specialist journal probably knows its reviewer base better than some more recently started generalist journals, for example.

Comment: @Anyon I'm pretty sure there is significant variation from journal to journal actually. The 69% agree-to-review rate in source 2 is well above anything I've seen. Looking at the source it seems probable that the reason is because it's a society journal with a special reviewer database. The first source shows similar variation, as well.